# Racket Scheme Deleting elemts of list in range

Tags: list, range, racket

How can I delete the values of list in range(a, b)? I tried with:

```
#lang racket

(define (remove L i n)
  (cond ((null? L)
         empty)
        ((> i 0)
         (cons (car L) (remove (cdr L) (sub1 i) n)))
        ((> n 0)
         (remove (cdr L) i (sub1 n)))
        (else
         L)))
```

But the result is:

```
(remove '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
'(1 2)
(remove '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 2 5)
'(1 2 8 9)
```

I would like to have:

```
(remove '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
'(1 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be easier to implement if you keep another parameter with the current index:

```
(define (remove L index start end)
  (cond ((null? L)
         empty)
        ((and (>= index start) (<= index end))
         (remove (cdr L) (add1 index) start end))
        (else
         (cons (car L) (remove (cdr L) (add1 index) start end)))))
```

If you don't want to add one extra parameter, we can always use a named `let`:

```
(define (remove L start end)
  (let loop ((lst L) (index 1))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           empty)
          ((and (>= index start) (<= index end))
           (loop (cdr lst) (add1 index)))
          (else
           (cons (car lst) (loop (cdr lst) (add1 index)))))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(remove '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
=> '(1 5)
(remove '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 2 5)
=> '(1 6 7 8 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs:

- You're using one-based indexing, so the first condition should be `(> i 1)`;
- Since the list shrinks in the first recursive clause, you need `(sub1 n)` there, too.
  Passing `n` makes it count how many elements to remove rather than the index of where to stop.